# Does $f_n(x)=\mathbb{1}_{A_n}$ converges point-wise, uniformly and in L1?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let,

$$f_n(x)=\mathbb{1}_{A_n}$$

where $A_n=[k2^{-m}, (k+1)2^{-m})$ with $m=[\log_2(n)]=\sup\left \{i \geq 0: 2^i \leq n \right \}$ and $k=n-2^m$.

Does $f_n(x)=\mathbb{1}_{A_n}$ converges point-wise, uniformly and in $L_1$?

According to my substitutions $A_n$ become $A_n=[0,1/n)$.

For pointwise convergence I think it does converge as $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \in A_n \\ 
0 & \text{if } x \notin A_n 
\end{cases}$$

But I do not know for uniformly and in $L_1$?

Comment: How can the limit function be defined in terms of $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $$f_\infty(x)=1_{\{0\}}=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } x=0 \\ 
0, & \text{if } x \ne 0 
\end{cases}.$$

Let $x$ be an arbitrary real number. If $x\le 0$ or $x\ge 1$ then $f_\infty (x)=f_n(x)$ for each $n$. If $0<x<1$ then $f_\infty (x)=f_n(x)=0$ for each $n>1/x$. So the sequence $\{f_n\}$ pointwise converges to the function $f_\infty$. It also converges to $f_\infty$ in $L_1$, because for each $n$

$$\|f_n-f_\infty\|_1=\int_{\Bbb R }|f_n(x)-f_\infty(x)|d\mu=\int_{[0;1/n]}1d\mu=1/n.$$

But the sequence $\{f_n\}$ cannot converge uniformly, because for each distinct $m$ and $n$ we have

$$\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R} |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|=1.$$